# Postman scripting: how to refrence a json node with web address for a name

Tags: javascript, json, jwt, postman

I'm currently working with a bearer token I need to get some data out of to continue a user journey. I found the following code that does the decoding for me

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
const payload = jsonData.Result.AccessToken.split('.')[1];  // Assuming the JWT is in id_token
const parsed = JSON.parse(atob(payload));
```

It uses atob sandboxed script to decode base 64 encoded payload, when decoded the payload looks a little like this:

```
{
  "http://mytestsite.uk/roles": [
    "user"
  ],
  "http://mytestsite.uk/id": "8d2c3de9-4fa2-a58e-68109d977",
  "http://mytestsite.uk/email": "tst3@mytestsite.uk",
  "sub": "500b416c8942bb0069b98a3c",
  "aud": "api.tst.mytestsite.uk",
  "iat": 1615544685,
  "exp": 1615631085
}
```

Normally, I would reference the payload body item I want (e.g. sub) like so:

```
pm.environment.set('sub', parsed.sub);
```

However, I want to reference "http://mytestsite.uk/id" and am uncertain how to do it.

`parsed.http://mytestsite.uk/id`

The above causes the script to error and I can't encode it, as that doesn't remove the dots, I obviously can't pass it as a string - I guess I'm unclear on how to correctly pass this name to reference the JSON object correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to reference it this way:

```
pm.environment.set('id', parsed['http://mytestsite.uk/id'])
```